# Could not connect to the debugger android emulator in visual studio 2019 for mac

Tags: android, macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

Im currently upgrade xamarin 5.0.0.2012 in mac laptop, after upgrade app running and showing **Could not connect to the debugger** and app close automatically.

Comment: Is there more details in output? First,  ensure xcode and visual studio version the latest.  You could try to reset the simulator. Clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is compile version xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2012 its support android 11 but i choose android 9. Finaly its working fine after i change and download android 11.